# How can I install a new preference pane in OSX 10.15.4?

Tags: macos, system-preferences

I've tried opening the .prefPane file and when I do so I can't open it because it is from an unidentified developer. It gives me to option to move it to the bin but I cannot authorise it from the privacy and security pane in system preferences because the pop-up window blocks me from using the app. Once I select cancel to avoid moving the file to the bin, when I click open anyway in the privacy & security pane it gives me an error saying it could not load the pane.

In the preference panes folder in Library/PreferencePanes, the file is there but it just says it 'couldn't open' the pane.

Comment: Never tried it on installing a pref pane, but the standard 'trick' to get Gatekeeper to allow something is right click/open instead of double-clicking on first run.

Comment: What happens if you put it in ~/Library/PreferencePanes?